# Access denied when browsing MVC web application with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, iis-7

I deployed my MVC web Application on a machine with windows server 2008 R2(web server) that joined the company domain (the web server is not the same server has the active directory installed) my application is using integrated windows authentication. When browsing the application I got prompted by dialog to enter the  login credentials and after login I got the error 
"403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

I configured the Application authentication on IIS I disabled all authentication types and enabled only the windows authentication and Asp.net impersonation, also I set the identity of the application pool to be "local system"

My Question are: How to fix this issue? and Why the browser (all browsers not only IE) prompt the user with user credentials dialogue?

Note: I Just created a web application using Visual studio 2015 and selected authentication type "windows authentication" and left the default configuration as it is.

Comment: The web server will look at the NTFS permissions to the files in the application. The easiest thing to do is ensure that the users are in a group that has the appropriate access permissions.

Comment: The user that login from the browser prompt is a member of the domain administrators and on the web server I set a permissions for everyone "Ful control" on the publish folder, also I tried to set the application pool identity to be local system or local service with the same error, I am very confused where is the fault

Comment: Finally I solved the issue by registering Asp.net by running "Aspnet_regiis.exe" from the command line- thank you :)

Comment: I am now working on the second issue; all browsers prompt the user to enter username and password for authentication although the windows user trying to open the web application is a member of the domain users, Any ideas?

Comment: @Abdelrahman - Can you try changing the following: Internet Options (Control Panel) -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Custom level -> User Authentication (Login) -> Prompt for username and password? Please check the option for local intranet / internet / trusted sites.

Comment: @Abdelrahman I can browse web page on IIS Express but when i browse on IIS it asks prompts login window, any idea?